# Getting null value in FormData in vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-resource

I am facing a big issue in Vue.js that when i am trying to send the data from Upload.vue to my controller in laravel 5.3  i am getting null values in it

My code is

My .vue file :

```
this.file = document.getElementById('video').files[0];            
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('video', this.file);
formData.append('uid', this.uid);
console.log(this.file);
console.log(this.uid);
console.log(formData);
this.$http.post('/upload',formData,.....
```

on console i am getting this :

this is when i print my "this.file"

```
File
lastModified:1475310793454
lastModifiedDate:Sat Oct 01 2016 14:03:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
name:"HQim.in.mp4"
size:20773807
type:"video/mp4"
webkitRelativePath:""
__proto__:File
```

when i console my formData i get this

```
FormData
__proto__:FormData
append:append()
constructor:FormData()
delete:delete()
entries:entries()
forEach:forEach()
get:get()
getAll:getAll()
has:has()
keys:keys()
set:set()
values:values()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator):()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag):"FormData"
__proto__:Object
```

nothing is available even when i appended i searched a lot but none benefitted 
 i am using "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.2"

Help me guys

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get

Comment: that does solves my error sir

Comment: Actually if i am passing only "uid" without using formdata that is passing but not the "file" so i have to use formdata but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

use this, may this help you...

```
npm install axios
```

or

```
bower install axios
```

then

```
import axios from 'axios'


            var datas = new FormData()

            datas.append('postMessage', this.postMessages)
            datas.append('postPicture', this.postPicture)


axios.post('your_url_here', datas , {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
                .then((response) => {
                    //if success
                    console.log(response)
                  },
                  (response) => {
                   //if error occures 
                   console.log(response)
                  })
```